# get_template_directory_uri() returns http instead of https on SSL site

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I know the topic has been already discussed, but it seems no solution was found. This is my case:
I have a wordpress site which now has SSL. However, in the theme resources are added as follows:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'spectrumwp-conditional', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/conditional.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

but get_template_directory_uri() returns the url with http not https.

Can you help me to solve this?

**Edit:**
I added this to my wp-config.php file

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Links to resources are shown with https:// but instead of, for example

https://www.exaple.com/wp-content/plugins/...

I have

https://www.example.com/plugins/LayerSlider/...

e.g. wp-content folder is missing

Final update:

uncommenting

```
 define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

and adding

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
 {  $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; }
```

just before the line

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

fixed the problem! Only, I recommend $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] is not used, as it may not be accurate enough.

**Solved!**

Comment: The last part you described fixed it for me too, thanks. I still don't understand why it needed to be done though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use is_ssl() to check if the site is running https:// or http://

Here is the hook to check and redirect :

```
function check_if_https() {
if ( !is_ssl() ) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
    exit();
  }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'check_if_https', 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! When I add this to my functions.php file, the site does not load and I have an error saying "Too many redirects"

Comment: Ok so you can try with changing the site URL's now.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Change site URL's in wp-config.php and theme's functions.php as per listed in the URL

Comment: I added the changes to wp-config and functions.php files, but I get The page isn’t redirecting properly

Answer (score 0):

Go into Settings -> General and check the Site URL.

It sounds like the problem you're having is this value is still HTTP, not HTTPS. Approach this change with caution. Make sure you have a working backup and a full understanding of why this URL needs to change as well as the impact it will have.

`get_template_directory_uri()` will automatically provide a HTTPS link when site URL is set correctly.

Comment: I have "a full understanding" and I did this a thousand times. Obviously wordpress does not recognize the https

Comment: Then I'd suggest you try outputting the value of `site_url` in PHP. Not a call to the option but the function instead.